# Can't edit the tag wiki for tag:synonyms

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/edit-tag-wiki/synonyms gives a 404

I assume this is a bug with the URL routing engine, where "synonyms" has special meaning.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't ask on meta.english?

Comment: I have gotten very little attention to bug reports made there.

Comment: @Rebecca, though now that you mention it, we have gotten no response at all to this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80891/possible-duplicate-message-is-difficult-to-notice-on-english-se either here or there

Answer (score 3):

Not only a problem for the tag `synonyms`

Also a problem for any tags named `info` `faq` `users` `hot` ... I went ahead and changed the routes a bit for editing tag wikis.

Should be deployed later today.

Comment: Thanks! Since you're already looking into issues on the tags page, maybe I could direct your attention to http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/886/tag-excerpt-inconsistently-displayed